# Dask array from_npy_stack misses info file

Tags: numpy, dask

**Action**

Trying to create a Dask array from a stack of `.npy` files not written by Dask.

**Problem**

Dask `from_npy_stack()` expects an `info` file, which is normally created by `to_npy_stack()` function when creating `.npy` stack with Dask.

**Attempts**

I found this PR (https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/686) with a description of how the info file is created

```
def to_npy_info(dirname, dtype, chunks, axis):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, 'info'), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump({'chunks': chunks, 'dtype': x.dtype, 'axis': axis}, f)
```

**Question**

How do I go about loading `.npy` stacks that are created outside of Dask?

**Example**

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

data_dir = Path('/home/tom/data/')

for i in range(3):
    data = np.zeros((2,2))
    np.save(data_dir.joinpath('{}.npy'.format(i)), data)

data = da.from_npy_stack('/home/tom/data')
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-54315c368240> in <module>()
      9     np.save(data_dir.joinpath('{}.npy'.format(i)), data)
     10 
---> 11 data = da.from_npy_stack('/home/tom/data/')

/home/tom/vue/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.pyc in from_npy_stack(dirname, mmap_mode)
   3722         Read data in memory map mode
   3723     """
-> 3724     with open(os.path.join(dirname, 'info'), 'rb') as f:
   3725         info = pickle.load(f)
   3726 

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tom/data/info'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `from_npy_stack` is short and simple. Agree that it probably ought to take the metadata as an optional argument for cases such as yours, but you could simply use the lines of code after loading the `"info"` file assuming you have the right values to. Some of these values, i.e., `dtype` and the shape of each array for making `chunks`, could presumably be obtained by looking at the first of the data files

```
name = 'from-npy-stack-%s' % dirname
keys = list(product([name], *[range(len(c)) for c in chunks]))
values = [(np.load, os.path.join(dirname, '%d.npy' % i), mmap_mode)
          for i in range(len(chunks[axis]))]
dsk = dict(zip(keys, values))

out = Array(dsk, name, chunks, dtype)
```

Also, note that we are constructing the names of the files here, but you might want to get those by doing a `listdir` or `glob`.

Comment: Thanks for this insight, I'll give it a try!